Is Proton "sieve" filter a programming language?
I'm going to post a question about how to solve a programming issue about the sieve filters by Proton Mail.
Searching for similar questions I didn't find anything that talks about this programming language. Is this not accepted on SO?

Are you referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sieve-language? There seem to be several questions about it on the site.

Even if you don't think about adding -language the sieve tag refers to [[tag:sieve-language]].

I searched for sieve in the search bar and I found misleading questions! Thanks for pointing out I should use tags

Sieve is very much a programming language, and is not exclusive to Proton. See the IETF standard or Wikipedia.
It is a domain-specific language, but those are on-topic at Stack Overflow, as long as your question pertains to programming.
As noted by cigien, it has a tag, sieve-language.
The tag sieve seems to be about sieve algorithms and thus not appropriate for the sieve language.

[sieve] should probably be renamed to [sieve-algorithm]

@Zoe Certainly a good idea. I've walked through all questions and retagged the 2 about the sieve language. These two are about a sieve function in GDAL which does not appear to be a sieve algorithm per the tag description afaict, so might need the tag removed.

We can deal with those later. I made the synonym, but haven't merged yet

... I forgot there's a search bug that requires merger now. Doing that now then

And [sieve] should probably be blocklisted because otherwise we'll be back here in no time.

sieve-language should be renamed to sieve-lang then, since that seems to be the new preferred naming pattern for ambiguous language tags.

@CorneliusRoemer That's not necessary. [sieve] is a synonym of [sieve-algorithm], so it can't reappear as a standalone tag (unless the synonym is removed, but that's an aside; removing synonyms requires a mod IIRC, so that won't just suddenly happen)

Thanks for teaching me something new :)
